# Ajax search with two dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to have a search to perform with two drop down box using ajax.
my main file is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#display").hide();
    var country ="";
    var option = "";
    $(".selectpicker").on('change', function () {
        option=$(this).val();
        myCall(option,country)
    });

    $(".bfh-selectbox-filter").on('blur', function () {
        country=$(this).val();
        myCall(option,country)
    });
});


function myCall(option,country){
    if (country.length > 0 && option.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {country: country, option:option},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#display").html(data).show();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#display").html('please select both the fields').show();
    }
}
```

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">

<select class="form-control selectpicker" required>
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="Batsman">Batsman</option>
    <option value="Bowler">Bowler</option>
    <option value="AllRounder">All rounder</option>
    <option value="Wicket Keeper">Wicket Keeper</option>
</select>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).find(".bfh-countries input[type=hidden]").attr("name","country");
});
```

This is my search.php code. I need the result to display after the search button is clicked. The result have to display with the combinatin of selection from these two drop downs.

```
if (isset($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['option'])) {
$country = trim($_POST['country']);
$option = trim($_POST['option']);
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_cricketerattr on users_id = tbl_users_users_id WHERE country='$keyword'  and option='$option'");

$result= "<ul id='playerlist'>";

while ($query3 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
    $result.= "<li id='list' onclick='fill()'>". $query3['first_name'].":". $query3['country']."</li>";
}
$result.= "</ul>";
echo $result;}
```

Please help!!

Comment: bit unclear..elaborate it

Comment: What is your question? Please explain a bit better.

Comment: where is your country dropdown in html??

Comment: The last part of the code is the html that I want to work with

Comment: I have used bootstrap form helpers country picker to display the countries

Comment: You should post your php, javascript, and html for what you want and not what you've done. We need to see what you've tried to be able to troubleshoot or show you what you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way add a search button to perform search.If you don't want you can use change event.

**your html and script:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#display").hide();
    var country ="";
    var option = "";
    $(".selectpicker").on('change', function () {
        option=$(this).val();
        myCall(option,country)
        });

    $("ul li a").on('click', function () {
        country=$(this).data("option");
        myCall(option,country)
        });
    });


function myCall(option,country){
    console.log(option+":"+country);
    if (country.length > 0 && option.length > 0) {
        $("#display").html("");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {country: country, option:option},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#display").html(data).show();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#display").html('please select both the fields').show();
   }
}
</script>


   <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">

        <select class="form-control selectpicker" required>
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
            <option value="Batsman">Batsman</option>
            <option value="Bowler">Bowler</option>
            <option value="AllRounder">All rounder</option>
            <option value="Wicket Keeper">Wicket Keeper</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">


        <div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
            <input type="hidden" value="">
            <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#">
                <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span>
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

            <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
                <input type="text" class="bfh-selectbox-filter">

                <div role="listbox">
                    <ul role="option">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="display"></div>
```

**your search.php:**  i have not tested it,see  if it has any problem feel free to ask.

```
 <?php
include('includes/db.php');
if (isset($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['option'])) {
$country = trim($_POST['country']);
$option = trim($_POST['option']);
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_cricketerattr on users_id = tbl_users_users_id WHERE country='$keyword'  and option='$option'");
$result= "<ul id='playerlist'>";
while ($query3 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
   $result.= "<li id='list' onclick='fill()'>". $query3['first_name'].":". $query3['country']."</li>";
}
$result.= "</ul>";
echo $result;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but there are issues, like my country drop down box is based on bootstrap form helper country picker. I dont knw a way to retrieve that from my database. can you please help me in that too.

Comment: To save the countries to the database I have used this piece of code <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(document).find(".bfh-countries input[type=hidden]").attr("name","country");
    });
</script>

Comment: it does not save to database.lets start one by one:do you have country list in db and you want to show it in the dropdow. in this case indise document ready make an ajax call get all country list and append it to your select box by looping all country.

Comment: There is no error in your code as far as I know. The drop down box that I have used for countries to display need to be attached with the search. That does not happen

Comment: you have country list in your database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90962/discussion-between-suchit-kumar-and-andrew).

Comment: no, I have used bootstrap form helpers country picker to display the countires. In my signup form the selected country saves into the database. But in my search form it has to retrieve from  the saved database records and the other drop down displaying player type.

Comment: click on  continue this discussion in chat.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to use ajax with two drop down options!

try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var country = $('.bfh-selectbox-filter').val();
var option = $('.selectpicker').val();
$(".selectpicker .bfh-selectbox-filter").on ('change', function () {
if (country !== '' && option !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: ["country": country, "option":option],
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#display").html('please select both the drop downs').show();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, I am trying to create that. Could you give me a sample code where I can actually use to test in my site?

Comment: I have tried, but I have no idea how to code the rest of the file to display the results

Comment: @Andrew what you tried?? where you're stuck?? update your post with your latest attempt

Answer (score 0):

For the search with dropdown, you should do it with `onchange()` event, like this

```
$(document).on("change","id or class of first dropdown",function () {
    var keyword = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: "keyword=" + keyword,
            success: function (html) {
                $("id or class of second dropdown").html(html).show();
            }
        });        
});
```

check [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html), it will help you.